# Are sets [0,1]×Z and <0,1>×Z with anti lexicographic order similar?

Tags: order-theory

Two sets are similar if there exists an increasing bijection between them. 
I don't know where to start, it seems like they are. I tried finding a similarity invariant in which they differ but can't find one.

Comment: For each of the two sets, check whether there exist an elements with only countably many elements above it

Comment: What is that anti lexicographical order thing?